# How can I align my bootrap tooltip to the front in bootstrap datatables with horizontal scroll?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, tooltip

I am using bootstrap tooltip inside my datatable. It worked well until I added `scrollX:true`. Since I did that, my tootip is covered by the table, I cannot make it visible, although I added `data-container="body"`:

```
  var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "columnDefs": [
      {"render": function (data, type, row) {
         return '<p data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-containter="body" title="edit" >edit</p>';
      }
  ],
....
```

Comment: is there a chance, tooltip's z-index is less than of scrollable DataTable?

Comment: @ygorbunkov how can I change tooltips z-index

Comment: right off the top of my head, if you include your own css for your custom elements, you may put there necessary section (with proper selector, that matches your tooltip) to override previous values. Of course, if it's loaded **after** the rest of  stylesheets.

Comment: Do you mean `.tooltip: z-index:9999999` Like this?

Comment: Cannot replicate this, can you create a fiddle or similar that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: @Jarla I wonder could it be your typo (data-containter="body") instead of data-container="body"?

Comment: @TrojanName OMG it was the type :((( Sorry, I did not see this!

Comment: @Jarla Happy to help!